# Armature not moving with object

Tags: mesh, game-engine, armature, physics

[image]

[image]

Hi! In the blender game engine, The object is the armature's parent, and has no collision physics. When I run the game however, the armature prevents the crocodile from falling or moving at all. If I add physics, it just begins to fly everywhere. How can I fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you must set the crocodile mesh to no colision and child of the armature, and the armature also to no colision and child of a cube that will be your colision bound. actually that cube is your crocodile and it will interact with physics and logic, the armature and the mesh must be merely visual.

Comment: Thanks! But can I still animate the croc using this setup though? If so how?

Comment: Yes you can normally.

Comment: Setting de mesh and the armature won't prevent you to animate it. if you are are basing the movement around of the crocodile in animation not in logic motion. so the put the move around animation on that cube that carry the whole thing, the body movements of the armature still the same.